# Accessing foreach loop value inside another foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have the following foreach loops in my program,

```
<?php
foreach ($edited_patient_payment_details as $patient_payment_details) {

    foreach ($original_patient_payment_details as $original_patient_payment_details) {

        if ($patient_payment_details['edit_walkin_patient_name'] === $original_patient_payment_details['walkin_patient_name']) {
        ?>
    <td style="color: red !important;" >
        <?php echo $patient_payment_details['edit_walkin_patient_name']; ?>
    </td>
        <?php 
        } else { 
        ?>
    <td>
        <?php echo $original_patient_payment_details['walkin_patient_name'];?>
    </td>
        <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I want to access the value in the  first foreach loop inside the  second foreach loop, how can I be able to access it/them?

Comment: Describe specific problem you facing with above code.

Answer (score 0):

The second for loop is inside the scope of the first for loop, so you can still access the first value as normal.